# How to get QR code from id?

Tags: spring, qr-code, thymeleaf

In my controller I have the following method:

```
import net.glxn.qrgen.QRCode;
import org.marcio.demospringboot.dao.FormationRepository;
import org.marcio.demospringboot.model.Formation;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.Map;

@Controller
public class FormationController {

@Autowired
private FormationRepository formationRepository;

@RequestMapping (value="formation/qr/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> qr(@PathVariable final Long id) {

    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = QRCode.from(formationRepository.findOne(id).toString()).stream();

    byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray();

    final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG);

    return new ResponseEntity<byte[]> (bytes, headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
}
```

In my html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>QR Code</title>
</head>
<body>

   <img th:src="@{/formation/qr/${id}}" />

</body>
</html>
```

This is the generated image:

[image]

I want to get user data from your "id". I am using a simple repository Spring `formationRepository` and the library `net.glxn.qrgen.QRCode`.The application works, but not generate the QR code with the user data regarding the "id". Thanks.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking here. Do you mean that you're just trying to look up a user by ID from your database? Isn't that what your `formationRepository` does? I'm not clear what the relevance of the QR code is...

Comment: Yes, it is that. I need to be returned me the data of a certain User from its "id" an image QR code. So I have used 'formationRepository'.

Comment: What is `formationRepository`? Just a normal Spring-data-style repository, or something else? Which bit of your code doesn't work? Presumably you successfully get `id` as a `Long`, then when you call `formationRepository.findOne()` you get back some kind of `User` object? Is that right? What is `QRCode`? A library of some kind, or something you've written yourself? Please don't just respond in a comment, but edit your original question to make things clearer.

Comment: What do you mean by "*not generate the QR code with the user data regarding the "id"*"? Doesn't generate a QR code at all? Generates it, but not what you'd expect? Everything just explodes?

Comment: I added the image generated on the above issue. The result of the QR code is something like "org.marcio.demospringboot.model.Formation@8eca290".  When I say User data, I mean the name, email, phone that corresponds to the "id" required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help and comments. They were all very helpful. I could solve the problem by upgrading to:

```
@RequestMapping (value="/formation/qr/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public HttpEntity<byte[]> qr(@PathVariable Long id) {
    byte[] bytes = QRCode.from(formationRepository.findOne(id).getTheme()
                   .toString()).withSize(120, 120).stream().toByteArray();
    final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG);
    headers.setContentLength(bytes.length);
    return new ResponseEntity<byte[]> (bytes, headers, HttpStatus.CREATED); 
}
```

The solution was `byte []bytes = QRCode.from(formation Repository.findOne (id).getTheme()`. So I got the registration content (getTheme) and presents it in QR code.

Answer (score 1):

Forgot '/' `@RequestMapping (value="/formation/qr/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)` before formation

EDIT:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = QRCode.from(formationRepository.findOne(id).toString()).stream();
byte[] data = stream.toByteArray();;
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG);
headers.setContentLength(data.length);

return new HttpEntity<byte[]>(data, headers);
```

This should work in order so the browser will understand it is an image and will show it

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The application works anyway. The problem I'm having is unable to generate the QR code from the "id" of the User.

Comment: Yes, he works. The result of the QR code is something like "org.marcio.demospringboot.model.Formation@8eca290". I would like to get the User data.

Comment: It should'nt be an image?

Comment: I added the image generated on the above issue